# Экспортировать данные из формы и отправить в Excel файл на Google Drive

Tags: php, javascript, html, form, google-api

Есть форма на сайте (с полями - First Name, Last Name, E-mail, Address, Room).
Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы после заполнения формы, введенные данные экспортировались в Excel файл на Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Гугл подсказал:

http://mycode.in.ua/php/google-api/google-spreadsheet-api.html

ищется в гугле за секунду по фразе "google spreadsheet api пример", первый результат из списка.